C++ ASAN kicking on decomposition declaration
I did a leetcode question and for following solution ASAN is kicking:
class Solution {
public:

    vector<int> rightSideView(TreeNode* root) {
        if (root == nullptr) return vector<int>();
        int ans[205];
        memset(ans, -1, sizeof ans);
        queue<pair<TreeNode*,int>> q;
        int ml = 0;
        q.push({root, 0});
        while(!q.empty()) {
            const auto &[node, level] = q.front();
            q.pop();
            ml = max(ml, level);
            if (ans[level] == -1) ans[level]=node->val;
            if (node->right != nullptr) q.push({node->right, level+1});
            if (node->left != nullptr) q.push({node->left, level+1});
        }
        return vector<int>(ans,ans+ml+1);
    }
};

If I replace const auto &[node,level]=q.front();q.pop(); with normal auto pair=q.front();node=pair.first,level=pair.second;, it works fine. Can anyone help me understand what's going on in above solution?

Can you make your code more readable with more spaces?

Done, although it shouldn't really matter, it's a small snippet of bfs code.

const auto &[node, level] = q.front();
q.pop();

You get a reference to the front node and then immediately destroy the node resulting in a dangling reference. Move q.pop(); to the loop body end.

Thanks! I didn't reliazed it is taking reference, my bad!

That's what the & means in a structured binding, yes.
